# AYUDA CON UN ALGORITMO

Tags: vb.net, poo, algoritmos

Tengo un problema que no he podido resolver, voy mas de 3 semanas pensándolo pero no lo he logrado,  así que decidí pedir ayuda por este medio, espero que puedan ayudarme.

El problema es el siguiente,

Se tiene una polígono compuestos por varios rectángulos como se muestra en la imagen, de esa imagen tengo las coordenadas de cada rectángulo, lo que se quiere hacer es aumentar sus espesores de tal forma de que no se afecte las longitudes entre cada rectángulo (Un ejemplo es el 2.49 que se muestra en la imagen 1 y la misma medida se ve en la imagen 2, como también el 1,04, entre otros), ademas de que si el rectángulo se encuentra en el medio de otro, este si deberá aumentar (se puede observar el 6.75 a 6.95, el criterio para aumentar los espesores es que este sea el doble en su nueva proporción, pero si es mayor a 0.20 no puede exceder de 0.40.

Se quiere llegar de esta figura,

[image: Imgaen 1]
A esta figura,

[image: ]]

No se si me entiendan, si no me comprenden por favor preguntarme...

NOTA: Lo estoy programando en Vb.net

Comment: Hola @JoseLuisRosalesMeza, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Hum.. veo que como consecuencia las longitudes de algunos rectángulos también deben variarse, además de su anchura. Por ejemplo el etiquetado como C ha de ser necesariamente más largo. No sé si tendrá solución en cualquier caso, me da que podría encontrar un contraejemplo en el que no se pueda aumentar todos los anchos respetando todas las distancias. En cualquier caso ¿qué estructura de datos tienes para almacenar la figura, los rectángulos que las componen, las distancias que deben respetarse, etc?

Comment: Si, el rectángulo C es mas grande debido a que crece el rectángulo 3, sin embargo las distancias entre cada uno se respetan,  en el rectángulo 5 no se respeta sus distancias entre los rectángulos E debido a que en medio de este existe otro rectángulo haciendo que la distancia entre ellos se mayor, pero si se respeta la distancia entre el borde inferior del rectángulo 5 y el C (2.53)... Ahora acerca de los datos,  cada rectángulo es un objeto, es decir que tengo creada una clase llamada RECTANGULOS y en ella se define las coordenadas de sus vértices.